# What is the difference between 'truth' and 'sincerity'

Tags: word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

I've just run into [trailer](https://youtu.be/Bk1HosLWM0o?t=95) where these two [words](http://wikidiff.com/truth/sincerity) '**art requires truth, not sincerity**' delivered as different or even oposite

I didn't find any substantial difference between words [truth](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/truth) and [sincerity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sincerity) on Oxford dictionary

---

Question

Could you please explain to me what the difference between these two words *(truth vs sincerity)*

Comment: "Truth" is not comparable to "sincerity", but "truthfulness" might  be. (n.b.: This is a dumbing-down of Colin's answer below.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Max. I'm puzzled why your dictionary doesn't help you distinguish them, because they're quite different.

Truth is a property of an utterance, whether or not it corresponds with objective (or sometimes subjective) reality.

Sincerity is a property of a person communicating, whether or not they believe in the truth of what they're saying.

If I tell you that John has left, but I am mistaken and he is still here, my statement is not true, but I am sincere.

If I think that John is still here, but tell you he has left, and I am wrong and he has indeed left, then my statement is true, but I am not sincere.

Comment: Curiously, there does seem to be a potential difference between ***sincerely*** and ***faithfully***. If we're told the ambassador presented his government's argument ***sincerely***, we'd probably assume he truly believed in the rightness of that position, and/or his presentation was passionate. But if he presented it ***faithfully***, although we'd know it was an ***accurate*** presentation, we might be inclined to suspect the ambassador didn't really endorse it (but he had to set it out, because that's his job).

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know you can't edit your post now but your excellent example clearly shows that the exact senses of *sincerely* and *faithfully* **are** different, not "potentially" so. Sincerity is measured against one's own belief; faithful against loyalty to one's duty to an idea or to another person.

Comment: That said, why did you even bring it up? No one else seems to have mentioned it.

Comment: @lly: I raised that distinction because this is a site for *learners*, and it seems to me dictionaries and etymological research might lead people to suppose ***sincere*** and ***faithful*** are both primarily concerned with *[potentially subjective] **belief*** rather than *[objective] **truth***. That distinction should be easily grasped in respect of ***true/sincere***, which may be why so many have upvoted Colin's answer (and in particular, the first sentence). Things aren't so obvious when we compare ***true/faithful***, which often mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Excellent question.  You can see that the definition of "sincerity" is:

> The absence of pretence, deceit, or hypocrisy.

A *sincere* person *believes* they are telling the truth, but may themselves be mistaken, deluded, or deceived (by someone else).

In the context of the movie trailer, "Art" is meant to be about things that are true, *from any point of view*.  No matter how *sincere* they are, a "real" artist must continually strive to break through preconceptions, misunderstandings, and delusions, and produce art that exposes underlying "truths".

Of course, this is still a vaguely sensational statement, meant to attract people to the movie.  Whether it's a valid statement, or exactly *how* an artist produces truth, is for you to decide.